# How to search a value in all tables in a database in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all the tables and column name having 'Hedge' as a column value.
How can I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the procedure from [here](http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated/) to perform such searches:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Copyright © 2002 Narayana Vyas Kondreddi. All rights reserved.
    -- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string
    -- Written by: Narayana Vyas Kondreddi
    -- Site: http://vyaskn.tripod.com
    -- Updated and tested by Tim Gaunt
    -- http://www.thesitedoctor.co.uk
    -- http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/02/19/Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database+Updated.aspx
    -- Tested on: SQL Server 7.0, SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2010
    -- Date modified: 03rd March 2011 19:00 GMT
    CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
    SET  @TableName = ''
    SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

    WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
            FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE         TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                AND    QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(
                        OBJECT_ID(
                            QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                             ), 'IsMSShipped'
                               ) = 0
        )

        PRINT 'Search within table ' + @TableName

        -- add exceptions here
        IF (@TableName LIKE '%AUDIT%')
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Skipped!'

            CONTINUE
        END

        WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            SET @ColumnName =
            (
                SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE         TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                    AND    TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                    AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
                    AND    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
            )

            IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL

            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #Results
                EXEC
                (
                    'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                )
            END
        END    
    END

    SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
    DROP TABLE #Results
END
GO

-- sample search
EXEC SearchAllTables N'Hedge'
```

However, be careful with this kind of search as they are very resource intensive. My customization is to not search within some known audit tables, as they were huge and the search was very slow.